How to change the font in a \pgftext block?
I am trying to change the font of a glyph inside a TikZ \pgftext block. However I get the error that appears to be a stack-overflow caused by \pgf@selectfontorig expanding to something that contains \pgf@selectfontorig. I've spent about half the day Googling and reading docs and source code, and I cannot figure out why this isn't working.
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=10000].
\pgf@selectfontorig ->\pgf@selectfontorig 
                                          \nullfont 
l.24     \draw [-{Glyph}] (E) to (F);
                                     
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

A minimal example is below:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\pgfdeclarearrow{
  name=Glyph,
  cache=false,
  bending mode=none,
  drawing code={
    \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpoint{-1.5ex}{-1ex}}{\pgfpoint{+2ex}{+2.5ex}}
    \pgfusepathqclip
    \pgftransformxshift{+0.1ex}
    \pgftransformyshift{-0.5ex}
    \pgftext[right,base]{\textsf{p}}
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikz{
    \node (E) {E};
    \node (F)[right of=E] {F};
    \draw [-{Glyph}] (E) to (F);
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Note that this code has been adapted from tikz-cd.
I have tried several different variations of the line in question:
    \pgftext[right,base]{\begingroup\fontfamily{cmss}\selectfont q\endgroup}

    \pgftext[right,base]{{\fontfamily{cmss}\selectfont q}}

    \pgftext[right,base]{\sffamily q}

and,
    {\sffamily \pgftext[right,base]{q}}

All produce the same error. Without any font setting code on that line works without issues, however the font is serif and I'm looking to create sans-serif arrow-tips.

Using $\mathsf{p}$ seems to work. Don't ask me why…
Why the nested tikzpicture?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\pgfdeclarearrow{
  name=Glyph,
  cache=false,
  bending mode=none,
  drawing code={
    \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpoint{-1.5ex}{-1ex}}{\pgfpoint{+2ex}{+2.5ex}}
    \pgfusepathqclip
    \pgftransformxshift{+0.1ex}
    \pgftransformyshift{-0.5ex}
    \pgftext[right,base]{$\mathsf{p}$}
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (E) {E};
    \node (F)[right of=E] {F};
    \draw [-{Glyph}] (E) to (F);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


